# All top bar popups showed below error popups

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, popups

> [image: popups]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click “Ask question” button.
2. Don’t fill anything
3. Click “Post your question”
4. See error popups
5. Open any popup from the top bar

Comment: You have missed the last step, which should be always "PROFIT!!!"

Comment: @nicael many of items are missed in this post. See the image.

Comment: Can reproduce on Chrome 65.0.3325.181, MacOS 10.13.2